# When porting python 2.5 to 3.X, how can I replace "from <module> import *"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.5

I've got a python 2.5 package with the following structure:

[image]

Config.py contains the following line:

```
from CommonDefines import *
```

Runnning this code in 3.7 gives the following exception:

> File "../../.\ConfigLib\Config.py", line 7, in 
>       from CommonDefines import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommonDefines'

Replacing that line with:

```
from .CommonDefines import *
```

... works in 3.7 but gives the following error in 2.5:

> SyntaxError: 'import *' not allowed with 'from .'

Is there a way to write this line so that works in both 2.5 and 3.X?

**EDIT:**

The following doesn't work, since the second import triggers a syntax error in 2.5

```
try:
    from CommonDefines import *
except:
    from .CommonDefines import *
```

> SyntaxError: 'import *' not allowed with 'from .'

Comment: Writing polyglot code that supports such an old version of Python (last 2.5.x release was in May 2011 - https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-256/) is going to be very hard ([`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/) only supports 2.7, for example). If you really need to continue to support 2.5, you may not be able to support 3.x with the same codebase.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: You should be able to write different imports wrapped in `try except` blocks. But as @jonrsharpe writes, I wouldn't recommend using the same codebase for both versions, because there has been a lot of changes between them both.

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as an answer! @HampusLarsson note that the OP has a *syntax* error, which is harder to paper over with `try:`/`except:`.

Comment: Correct. I've added an edit addressing that.

Comment: IMHO `*` imports are an anti-pattern anyway, so if I were you, I'd just replace the `*` with the concrete names imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a proper name-by-name import, but this can be done in a hacky way, for your personal use, using `exec`:

```
try:
    from CommonDefines import *
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    exec('from .CommonDefines import *')
```

You can even swap them and catch the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it seems to work so far.